# AWS Codepipeline - Deploy on multiple environments at once

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, pipeline, aws-codepipeline

I'm using Codepipeline and CloudFormation and wanted to know if we can deploy the code at once on multiple environments like lab,dev & prod using Codepipeline, to have an option to select which and which envs the code should be deployed on? Is this possible or not? and how can I achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible, AWS even provides a lot of resources / guides for that topic for example [this walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-basic-walkthrough.html) helps you building a pipeline with a production and a staging stack.